# Grails: Read Oracle Database User Roles

Tags: oracle, grails, groovy, permissions, roles

I'm working on a Groovy/Grails project that will display the roles that a user is currently assigned in an Oracle database.  Is it possible to query this information from the Oracle server via Groovy/Grails?  If it is, any pointers on how to do this are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `spring-security` plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of oracle metadata views available. First of all there is a prefix DBA_, ALL_, USER_ describes how much data you will see (depending on your permissions). I will list only DBA_ prefix, you could replace it with more restrictive prefix.

You will be interested in views:

```
DBA_ROLES
DBA_ROLE_PRIVS
ROLE_TAB_PRIVS
DBA_TAB_PRIVS
DBA_USERS
SESSION_PRIVS
SESSION_ROLES
TABLE_PRIVILEGES
```